# Nodejs application hangs on heavy requests

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I am using, Nodejs express server with pg-promise. I have some queries in the database which takes alot of time to return result. For such queries I set a timeout for 3sec which fails the promise, if the query pg-promise query takes longer and the server returns an error. However, the issue is that if I send subsequent requests with same (heavy) queries, the application hangs and takes time to start processing the new request. It doesnot throw any error, that is why it is difficult to debug. I was wondering what can be the reason for the node application to hang?

Comment: Don't use javascript for big project!!!!

Comment: @HaykManasyan its not a big project. It's just big queries to db which fetches many rows

Comment: I rather doubt folks can help you without seeing your code.  There's no reason that node.js would "hang" because of a long query.  In fact, I don't even know what that really means "to hang".  If you are doing very time consuming database queries and then when you try to do multiple of them, it's just too much load, then the issue is probably with either your database or how you are using your database, neither of which are likely node.js issues.  You need to either restructure your data so you can accomplish your goal with faster queries or you need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: @NaufalKhalid you can use `explain` for localizing your problem. You should understand if your problem comes from DB or Node.JS. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html

Comment: I know that the queries are expensive, therefore, I set timeouts using pg promise to return an error if the query is taking too long.
 
This is an example code:

`return db.any("select * from users")
           .then(x => { 
             return x
            })
            .timeout(3000)
            .error(err => {
             return err})
`

Logically, this code should return an error if the query takes more than 3s. However the application takes much more time to process the queries

Comment: @NaufalKhalid This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160177/query-timeout-in-pg-promise

Answer (score 0):

Whenever somebody comes up with a question about queries execution taking too long at the very start, it always points at the misunderstanding of the fundamentals around development and implementation of database services.

Those issue typically root from the following problems:

- Bad database design, or lack of essential performance considerations
- Bad query execution planning, i.e. use of very inefficient query logic
- Bad use of the connection pool, i.e. the database connectivity issues
- Combinations of the above

So when you are trying address such a huge pool of possible problems with a brief problem description, and without any code examples, you will never get any usable answer. It is far too broad, and it would require to cover too many topics pertaining to writing database services.